# How to get Meta Description tag of a web page using python or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, meta-tags

I am tryin to make a programme which can get the `<meta> name="Description" content="something...."</meta>`
of an url. But I am not able to do it. Can somone please help me with it!

Comment: @ did you try ```Beautifulsoup``` ?

Comment: use BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup:

```
import bs4

# Retrieve html

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.find("meta", {"name" : "Description"})
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `beautifulsoup`. With code below you are good to go I guess

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("your link"), 'html.parser')
meta_part = soup.find("meta")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the browser you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
const author = document.querySelector("meta[name='author']");
const title = document.querySelector("meta[name='title']");

console.log(author.content);
console.log(title.content);
```

```html
<meta name="author" content="me <author@me.example>">
<meta name="title" content="foo">
```